# How to set a value in ComboBox2 as a list/array depending on the selection of an item in ComboBox1?

Tags: python, customtkinter

I want to create simple software for my work environment, and among the first things the user enters input parameters through 2 ComboBoxes.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to set the "value=" so that based on the selection in ComboBox1 it sets the list/array to ComboBox2.

To explain it as simply as possible, I tried it through these parameters:

```
BMW = ["iX", "iX M60", "i7"]
Audi = ["A1", "A3", "A4"]


optionmenu_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="")

Car_Brand_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=frame_settings,
                                             width=250,
                                             values=["Audi", "BMW", "Volkswagen"],
                                             variable=optionmenu_var)

Car_Brand_combobox.place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

if Car_Brand_combobox == "BMW":
    Car_Model_List = BMW
if Car_Brand_combobox == "Audi":
    Car_Model_List = Audi

Car_Model_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=frame_settings,
                                                 width=250,
                                                 values=Car_Model_List,
                                                 variable=optionmenu_var)

Car_Model_combobox.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
```

I used the brands and models of the cars for the demonstration, in the final it will be used differently. When I run the program, it returns this text: 'type' object is not iterable.